# Azure Logic App output structure into json format

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get azure log analytics details in output structure from Azure Logic App as below. But getting in different way.
Need suggestion to change in code. Thanks in advance.

Expected structure:

```
{
    "id": "logAnalyticsId",
    "workspaces": [
        {
                "location": {
                "workspaceId": "hjbffe8a-7560-410f-b92b-30d65f9e4c0d",
                "workspaceKey": "Gy+me/auFCuWQ+s8bVq1Wdr25djtGQmoazh9fxGvRRNpkAWdkFPAcDXi5wEsVZk4aox2aCsoBlYgAx3l9ksHUQ==",
                "workspaceName": "demo-law-1"
            }
        },
            {
                "location": {
                "workspaceId": "f24ty93e-0063-450a-ab4a-11785af7eceb",
                "workspaceKey": "DhdsVwBtX8wniL34jGn8clFqNYT10N1DclfluAlb0pCNiv4R6hKfRv4OSY+MKCiCSrtkIELx8cKr9/g3Zf57Lg==",
                "workspaceName": "demo-law-2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Getting a structure like below:

```
{
  "id": "logAnalyticsId",
  "location": {
    "workspaceId": [
      "hjbffe8a-7560-410f-b92b-30d65f9e4c0d",
      "f24ty93e-0063-450a-ab4a-11785af7eceb"
    ],
    "workspaceKey": [
      "Gy+me/auFCuWQ+s8bVq1Wdr25djtGQmoazh9fxGvRRNpkAWdkFPAcDXi5wEsVZk4aox2aCsoBlYgAx3l9ksHUQ==",
      "DhdsVwBtX8wniL34jGn8clFqNYT10N1DclfluAlb0pCNiv4R6hKfRv4OSY+MKCiCSrtkIELx8cKr9/g3Zf57Lg=="
    ],
    "workspaceName": [
      "demo-law-1",
      "demo-law-2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Using below code in Logic App.

https://github.com/prannoy47/azure-logic-app/blob/master/logic-app

Comment: It solved my problem. But I have another doubt. If the location is dynamic is it possible as below:  [https://github.com/prannoy47/azure-logic-app/edit/master/dynamic-env](https://github.com/prannoy47/azure-logic-app/edit/master/dynamic-env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use "liquid" to transform your json data, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform).

Below I post the solution for your reference:

**1.** You need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account#create-integration-account) an integration account and then [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account#link-to-logic-app) this integration account to your logic app.

**2.** Create a liquid template, please refer to my liquid template below:

```
{% assign ids = content.location.workspaceId %}
{% assign keys = content.location.workspaceKey %}
{% assign names = content.location.workspaceName %}

{
    "id":"{{content.id}}",
    "workspaces":[
        {%- for item in ids -%}
            {%- if forloop.Last == true -%}
                {
                    "location": {
                        "workspaceId": "{{ids[forloop.index0]}}",
                        "workspaceKey": "{{keys[forloop.index0]}}",
                        "workspaceName": "{{names[forloop.index0]}}"
                    }
                }
            {%- else -%}
                {
                    "location": {
                        "workspaceId": "{{ids[forloop.index0]}}",
                        "workspaceKey": "{{keys[forloop.index0]}}",
                        "workspaceName": "{{names[forloop.index0]}}"
                    }
                },
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    ]
}
```

**3.** Save this template as type of ".liquid"(such as "testMap.liquid") and upload it to your integration account, please refer to the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#create-liquid-template-or-map-for-your-integration-account).

**4.** Go to your logic app and create a "Transform JSON to JSON" action, choose the "testMap" which we uploaded above (shown as the screenshot below):
[image]

The "Content" in the screenshot above is the json data you get currently.

After the "Transform JSON to JSON" action, it will response the json structure you expected.
[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: I have another doubt. If the location is dynamic is it possible as below:  [https://github.com/prannoy47/azure-logic-app/edit/master/dynamic-env](https://github.com/prannoy47/azure-logic-app/edit/master/dynamic-env)

Comment: Hi @PrannoySeal It seems the json data you provided is invalid json. Could you please update it. I think this requirement can be implemented, I will try to help you solve this problem tomorrow because I'm getting off work. Of course you can create another post and maybe some one else will help you solve it.

Comment: I will update the json. Also, I am new to liquid language, if you provide me any guide link that will be helpful

Comment: I have updated as required. Many thanks for the help on initial stage.

Comment: @PrannoySeal Sorry I can't see the json data now, open the github link you provided, it shows page not found.

Comment: I have removed the file from github. Now it is working. Have modified as per requirement.

Comment: @PrannoySeal So your problem was solved, right ? Here is a [document](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/) about liquid which I refer to.